# Why is this comparison check not working on a Windows box?

Tags: conditionals, global-variables, advanced-conditionals

I've set up the following code on a site. On my Mac (dev version - identical to the running live code) the template looks like this:

```
{if '{current_path}'=='/'}
...
{/if}
```

And this works fine. But the same code on the live version simply does not get past this if statement.

Rendering `{current_path}` out to the page before or after the `if` statement shows its value as `/`, but I can't get anything to evaluate inside the `if`.

Any clue as to what's going on?

Considerations: the live server is a Windows box.

Comment: What would be the value of current_path on the windows box?

Comment: @foamcow It comes out as `/` on the Windows box right before the `if`

Comment: OK, and what is inside the if statement? Does the code execute correctly if you remove the conditional from around it?

Comment: @foamcow yes perfectly. in fact I've had to do that now just to get it to work... but it's not with the desired result because I can't get this `if` to work

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug, to me. Probably something related to different PHP between the environments. Starting with version 2.9, EECMS changes the way conditionals are evaluated. So this bug is probably gone.

Conditionals should always use the syntax:

```
{if current_path == "/"}
...
{/if}
```

But `{current_path}` is parsed at the end of parsing stages. This conditional will be evaluated after all modules and plugins run.

Why not just check for `{segment_1}`?

```
{if segment_1 == ""}
...
{/if}
```